# how to get a belongsToMany() query from a collection ? MySQL/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.4.22 (the newest one). In MySQL, I have two tables, `tag_categories` and `tags`, which form a many-to-many relationship. What I need is a query which returns all the tags for the selected categories. I know how to solve this when I have only one object, and I know how to solve this with querying and looping each of those objects, but there has to be a query or eloquent based solution for the whole thing?

I understand the code below doesn't work because I'm using `->belongsToMany` on a collection rather than an object, but how to I bridge this gap the simplest way?

```php
$resultingTags = TagCategory::whereIn('id', $chosenCategoriesIds)
                              ->belongsToMany(Tag::Class)->get();

dd($resultingTags);
```

Comment: If you did it like this what do you get?

$resultingTags = TagCategory::whereIn('id', $chosenCategoriesIds)->tags;

Comment: @OmarTarek that would result in an error because you're looking for a `tags` property on the query builder which won't exist.  (whereIn returns a Query Builder instance, not a model)

Comment: I see, then what if something like this?  $resultingTags = TagCategory::whereIn('id', $chosenCategoriesIds)->tags()->all();

Comment: $resultingTags = TagCategory::whereIn('id', $chosenCategoriesIds)->tags()->get(); is what I initially tried, but the tags() method that I use to call the belongsToMany() from within the model refuses to work when used on a collection, since model is for handling objects, from how I understand it.

Comment: Ok one more, have you tried
$resultingTags = TagCategory::whereIn('id', $chosenCategoriesIds)->get('tags');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

belongsToMany generally belongs in the model class, not a method called on the fly.  When looking to eager load the relationship, you then call the `with()` method on the query builder.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

ex:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}

// Query
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
$rolesOfFirstUser = $users->first()->roles;
```

If you're trying to get all the tags of the given categories, then you should be querying tags, not tag_categories.

```
Tag::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($chosenCategoriesIds) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $chosenCategoriesIds);
})->get();
```

Comment: I actually  already did have the belongsToMany() method in the model like you suggested here, I just tried to not bloat my question, perhaps for the worse. Thank you for the response, I'll try and see what the with() method does for me here.

Comment: Keep in mind, you don't need to eager load, it just makes it faster.  You should be able to access the `tags` (or in this example `roles`) property on any model in the collection regardless of eager loading (it just requires one query per model without eager loading).

Comment: @Devon, You need to use eager load if you are expecting high volume of traffic and querys to the database. If you don't you will create a N + 1 problem. See https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabcontrib/article/n_plus_one/

Comment: @Staafsak that's pretty much what I just wrote... hence the "requires one query per model without eager loading" lol

Comment: Actually what I was looking for is for a way to get the resulting collection of all the tags which were related to the collection of chosen tagCategories. From your solution I am once again looping through each object and populating an array, something where I was at the start. Perhaps I didn't formulate my question well enough.

Comment: @MarkoAntonić see if my update gets you anywhere.  Look in the querying relationships section of the Laravel docs, Laravel is pretty well documented.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. I just had to specify that 'id' was in fact 'tag_categories.id' , since i was receiving an ambiguity error. Kudos.
I promise I was looking through the documentation and google for a while before asking here, but this is quite a complicated query and I am only in the coding world for a couple of months.

Answer (score 2):

This is [One-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relation

Define relation at `TagCategory` model at `app/TagCategory.php`

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Tag');
}
```

And handle at your `Controller`

```
$resultingTags = TagCategory::whereIn('id', $chosenCategoriesIds)->with(['tags'])->get();
```

---

If you want define [Many-To-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation for this case

You need to have 3 tables `tags`, `tag_categories`, `tag_tag_category`

Define relation at `TagCategory` model at `app/TagCategory.php`

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'tag_tag_category', 'tagcategory_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

And handle at your `Controller`

```
$resultingTags = TagCategory::whereIn('id', $chosenCategoriesIds)->with(['tags'])->get();
```

Comment: It is in fact a Many-to-Many relationship. One tag can belong to multiple Categories just like A Category has many tags. Perhaps the question title was a bit misleading.

Comment: @MarkoAntonić So you need to have 3 tables `tags`, `categories`, `tag_category`.

Comment: tags, tag_categories, and tag_tag_category as the pivot table to be exact. I understand how these names were confusing.